# Validator causes improper behavior for double click check

Tags: asp.net

I have following script to `prevent a button from submitting twice` by double clicking. It works fine.

But the scenario gets clumsy when I added a `Required Field validator`. If I try to submit with a blank value in textbox, the validator fires. But when I entered value in textbox and try to submit again it does not do a postback.

I understand the reason, in the first button click itself, the variable isActionInProgress is set as 'Yes' irrespective of the validation error.

What is the best way to overcome this challenge?

**MARK UP**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {



        var isActionInProgress = 'No';

        $('.myButton').click(function (e) {

            if (isActionInProgress == 'No') {
                isActionInProgress = 'Yes';
            }
            else {
                e.preventDefault();
                //alert('STOP');
            }

        });


    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="myButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="ButtonClick"
        OnClick="Button1_Click" />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtEmpName"
        runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ValidationGroup="ButtonClick" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

REFERENCES

1. [Page_ClientValidate is validating multiple times.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969465/problem-with-page-clientvalidate)
2. [Hide redundant error message in ASP.Net ValidationSummary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565718/hide-redundant-error-message-in-asp-net-validationsummary)
3. [MSDN - ASP.NET Validation in Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think somthin like  this:

```
 $('.myButton').click(function (e) {
        if(Page_IsValid){
        if (isActionInProgress == 'No') {
            isActionInProgress = 'Yes';
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
            //alert('STOP');
        }
      }

    });
```

Comment: If validator validate correct Page_IsValid will be true. Your click doesn't fire after validation because your script works in any case and prevent second click. Now this occures only if validation was correct