# Multiple form submits with enterkey

Tags: angular, forms

I have an angular form, when the focus is on submit button and user press and hold submit button it submits the form multiple times. 
I can disable the button on submit, but i have multiple forms 
Is there a best way to handle this globally using angular or html.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to apply for **debouncing**. You can use it easily in js. If you use lodash library it is even easier. Some helpful links;

- https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/
- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce

On the other hand, there is a similar issue in the following link and it can help you to think in another way. 
[Preventing multiple clicks on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715075/preventing-multiple-clicks-on-button)